# Send to java App an inputStream by webbrowser control in c#

Tags: c#, java, parsing, browser, inputstream

i have a Java application for parsing web page. However after that i do this application, i need to use the webbrowser control in c# app for the navigation. So I thought that take the page by webBrowser control in c# application, and send the inputStream to my java app (by socket). My java app work with un inputStream, but I don't know how extract the inputStream and if this is possible from c#.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as a bad practice. I would rather use some sort of SOAP in this scenario.

However, if you really need to do what you are saying... you can send a HTTP POST Request and put whatever you want in the content-body (also know as entity). On the other end you just need to read the body from the HTTP request.

You can try this:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx

or this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1128496.aspx/1

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Now i try to receive the HTMLContent in c# by webBrowser.DocumentText and send this to java app by socket, but maybe the string is too long. I would use the pipe or better a shared memory, because both app are in client machine. Can you help me?

Comment: I have zero knowledge in c# therefore I can not offer much help. If you have problems with the content being too long it may help to use multipart in your transfer.